# Oracle - Why should I use packages instead of standalone procedures or functions

Tags: oracle, database-design, plsql

I searched google but did not find any satisfying answer as to why I should use packages.

I know that a package is a bundle of procedures, functions and different variables. As I understand it sort of corresponds to object in OOP. But of course there's nothing like instantiating different instances of a package so that each instance would have different property values and behave differently.

Then what is the advantage of using packages when I can just create a standalone procedure and call it independently?

Comment: [Tom Kyte's opinion](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:7452431376537)

Comment: Packages are **not** about "objects". An Oracle (object) `TYPE` with the ability to have its own methods and constructors is the equivalent thing to an object in OOP.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Packages provide the following advantages:

1. Cohesion: all the procedures and functions relating to a specfic sub-system are in one program unit.  This is just good design practice but it's also easier to manage, e.g. in source control.
2. Constants, sub-types and other useful things: there's more to PL/SQL than stored procedures.  Anything we can define in a package spec can be shared with other programs, for instance user-defined exceptions.
3. Overloading: the ability to define a procedure or function with the same name but different signatures.
4. Security: defining private procedures in the package body which can only be used by the package because they aren't exposed in the specification.
5. Sharing common code: another benefit of private procedures.
6. We only need to grant EXECUTE on a package rather than on several procedures.

Comment: Cohesion! Well this is other way in java while writing classes, we should break our code to multiple classes if its growing, for source control systems it's a nightmare if multiple people are pushing and merging the code from a single source file.

Comment: @ManishBansal - this comes down to proper design and separation of responsibilities. If we have multiple people simultaneously working on the same package (class in Java) there's something seriously awry with our application architecture.

Answer (score 11):

As described in [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/packages.htm#i2408), packages are good because of:

- modularity
- easier application design
- information hiding
- added functionality
- better performance

Details on each reason are explained in docs.