# Oracle,Spring: Using package name when calling stored procedure

Tags: spring, oracle, jdbc

What are the benefits of calling a stored procedure via its package name E.g. package.mystoredproc versus a direct call E.g. mystoredproc?

Does this give extra information to the calling code or is it just a good convention to use?

I've created a stored procedure which doesn't live in a package. I can execute the call without any problems however when the procedure was moved into a replicated environment where synonyms are used i ran into a problem whereby i had to include the schema name when calling the procedure.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12934984/oracle-why-should-i-use-packages-instead-if-standalone-procedures-or-functions